# Derivative of a parallel

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature, parametrization, arc-length

I'm fully aware of the fact that there is something simple here that I am just not seeing and it's not been four hours of trying to substitute every potential rewrite of $n'(t)$ but can someone kindly explain to me the following. Given the arc-length-parametrised curve $γ(t)$ and its parallel $p(t)$ s.t.
$$p(t)=γ(t)+dn(t)$$
$$\text{ and } n(t) \text{is the unit normal vector to } γ(t)$$ 
Why does this hold?
$$p′(t)=γ′(t)+dn′(t)=(1−k(t)d)γ′(t)$$ 
$$ \text{where } k(t) \text{ is the curvature of } γ(t)$$

Comment: $k$ would be the curvature?

Comment: Yes, my bad. I've edited that.

Comment: isn't $n'(t)=-k(t) \gamma'(t)$ a standard result?

Comment: I thought it was $n'(t)=-k(t)\gamma'(t)-\tau(t)b(t)$ and $b$ is the bi-normal vector to $\gamma'(t) $ and $n(t)$

Comment: @Gracious Presumably $\gamma$ is a planar curve (see my answer) so that $\tau \equiv 0$.

Comment: Yeah, I just saw that! Thanks guys :):)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding both sides of the last equality shows that the equality is equivalent to (suppressing parameters in most places throughout) $$n' = - k \gamma' .$$
But this follows from the Frenet-Serret equations for planar curves:
\begin{align*}
{\bf T}' &= \phantom{-k {\bf T}+}k n \\
      n' &=          -k {\bf T}
\end{align*}
Here $\bf T$ is the unit tangent vector; since $\gamma$ is parameterized by arc length, $\gamma' = {\bf T}$.

If you're only familiar with the more commonly seen Frenet-Serret equations for space curves, you can recover the plane curve version just by viewing $\gamma$ as the space curve $t \mapsto (\gamma(t), 0)$; since the curve is planar, the torsion is $\tau \equiv 0$.